# Сортировка последовательности сгрупированных строк по значению одной из строк

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Есть следующая схема базы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется выбрать все записи из таблицы Lead вместе с Value из таблицы Leads2Fields и Name из таблица Fields, и отсортировать по значению колонки Value у которого Field.Name = 'First Name'(например). В EF Core запрос выглядит так:

```
Context.LeadsImpl.Where(l => l.UserId == userId).Include(l => l.Leads2Fields).ThenInclude(l => l.Field)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Leads2Fields.FirstOrDefault(l2f => l2f.Field.Name == "First Name").Value)
                    .Skip(start).Take(length);
```

Требуется переписать данную LINQ-у в чистый sql запрос. Если делать запрос с join-ами на SQL-е то в результате строки для 1 Lead-а будут дублироваться только раз сколько у него есть Leads2Fields. Так вопрос, можно ли отсортировать строки всех лидов по значению какой-либо колонки. Т.е. один лид имеет First Name = 1, другой First Name = 2, и требуется чтобы все остальные строки пришли к такому порядку: сначало идут строки первого лида, затем строки сторого лида.

---

Скрипт с ордерм но без пэйджинга

```
SELECT l."Id", l2f."Id" Lead2FieldId, l."UserId", l2f."FieldId", l2f."Value", f."Section", f."Type", f."Name"
            FROM public."Leads_22" as l INNER JOIN "Leads_222Fields_22" l2f ON l2f."LeadId" = l."Id"
            INNER JOIN "Fields_22" f ON f."Id" = l2f."FieldId"
            WHERE "UserId" = 1
            ORDER BY (
                SELECT l2f."Value"
                FROM "Leads_222Fields_22" AS l2f
                INNER JOIN "Fields_22" AS "l2f.Field" ON l2f."FieldId" = "l2f.Field"."Id"
                WHERE ("l2f.Field"."Name" = 'First Name') AND (l."Id" = l2f."LeadId")
                LIMIT 1
            ) ASC, l."Id"
```

Comment: Идеологически - что-то типа `ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN Field.Name = 'First Name' THEN Leads2Fields.Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY Leads.ID)`. На практике разумнее спихнуть всё, включая это вычисление, в CTE.

Comment: @Akina если с ордером разобрался, то с пэйджингом до сих пор проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просмотрев логи postgresql-а нашёл следующую query:

```
   SELECT "l.Leads_222Fields_22"."Id", "l.Leads_222Fields_22"."FieldId", "l.Leads_222Fields_22"."LeadId", "l.Leads_222Fields_22"."Value", "l.Field"."Id", "l.Field"."IsSystem", "l.Field"."Name", "l.Field"."ObjectType", "l.Field"."Options", "l.Field"."ReadOnly", "l.Field"."Required", "l.Field"."Section", "l.Field"."Type"
        FROM "Leads_222Fields_22" AS "l.Leads_222Fields_22"
        INNER JOIN "Fields_22" AS "l.Field" ON "l.Leads_222Fields_22"."FieldId" = "l.Field"."Id"
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT l0."Id", (
                SELECT l2f1."Value"
                FROM "Leads_222Fields_22" AS l2f1
                INNER JOIN "Fields_22" AS "l2f.Field1" ON l2f1."FieldId" = "l2f.Field1"."Id"
                WHERE ("l2f.Field1"."Name" = 'First Name') AND (l0."Id" = l2f1."LeadId")
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS c
            FROM "Leads_22" AS l0
            WHERE l0."UserId" = 1
            ORDER BY (
                SELECT l2f0."Value"
                FROM "Leads_222Fields_22" AS l2f0
                INNER JOIN "Fields_22" AS "l2f.Field0" ON l2f0."FieldId" = "l2f.Field0"."Id"
                WHERE ("l2f.Field0"."Name" = 'First Name') AND (l0."Id" = l2f0."LeadId")
                LIMIT 1
            ) , l0."Id"
            LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
        ) AS t ON "l.Leads_222Fields_22"."LeadId" = t."Id"
        ORDER BY t.c DESC, t."Id"
```

20 - количество айтемов, 0 - С какого айтема начинать выборку